# How to update missing values in child records?

Tags: sql

I have a table `calendar` with integer fields `calendarid`, `parentid`, `projectid`.
Child records are defined by having `parentid` filled in pointing to the `calendarid` key field of the parent record.

Error situation that needs to be fixed in an update query:

*If parent records have `projectid` filled in and children don't: copy `projectid` from parent to children.*

This is only one level deep, number of children is [0..n]

To get all the children with missing `projectid` I have this,
but I'm wrestling with building this into the proper update query:

```
select * from calendar o
where (coalesce(o.projectid,0)=0) and (coalesce(o.parentid,0)<>0)
and exists(select calendar_id from calendar i
           where (i.calendar_id=o.parentid)
           and (coalesce(i.projectid,0) <> 0)
          )
```

What would be the update query (in vanilla SQL because it has to work on several versions of Firebird, SQL Server, and Oracle)?.

(Note that in the current situation child records may have a `projectid` that's different from the parent projectid, so simple overwriting all child values is not an option)

Comment: You said a record is recognized as child by the entry in the `parentid` field.  If that field is empty, you want to fill it in based on the record's relation to the parent.  But that relationship is determined using that field.  This seems circular...?

Comment: @smandoli I want *projectid* filled in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of syntax variation between databases for these kind of updates.

```
update
    calendar
set
    projectid = (select projectid from calendar c where calendar.parentid = c.calendarid)
where
    projectid is null;
```

is fairly standards compliant and should work in most places.

This is assuming "not filled in" means null.

Comment: Agree, `coalesce()` doesn't have wide support.

Comment: Ah, this is beautifully simple. It works because my parent records don't have (grand)parent records and then setting null to null does no harm ;-)
In all our cases, coalesce() will work. That lets me convert 0 as well, should that occur in the children.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the query you already have and join it to the parent.

You could change it to update like so:

```
UPDATE o
Set o.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
from calendar o join calendar p on p.calendarId = o.ParentId
where (coalesce(o.projectid,0)=0) and (coalesce(o.parentid,0)<>0)
and exists(select calendar_id from calendar i
           where (i.calendar_id=o.parentid)
           and (coalesce(i.projectid,0) <> 0)
          )
```